Trying to find a subring of $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$, the quaternions
I already showed that a subring of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, and now I'm moving up. I'm looking to generalize this for all dimensions, but I know the octonions lose associativity, so I'm wondering how that's gonna work out. I came up with matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c&d\\\ -b&a&-d&c\\\ c&d&a&b\\\ -d&c&-b&a\end{pmatrix}$, but I'm wondering if I should make the bottom left quadrant negative, so it's a truly recursive process. I tried multiplication, and I see that these matrices are closed under multiplication and obviously addition. I feel like the bottom left should still be negative though, as then there would be two negative c's, which represent the imaginary unit j. The other two, i and k, both have two negatives, so it makes sense. I ran it through a calculator, and it seems like both of these representations are closed under multiplication. So is there a reason to choose one over the other?
Edit: So apparently I was wrong. The correct matrix should be in the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c&d\\-b&a&d&-c\\-c&-d&a&b\\-d&c&-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ It looks very close to mine if I flipped the bottom left signs, but it centers the negativity around c instead of d. I'm not sure how this was justified when coming up with it, but I obviously believe it's right. This really threw a wrench in my easy recursive construction.

In your first version, $(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,1,0)$ produces a singular matrix. The second version is fine.

Define the function $\Phi : \mathbb{H} \to M_4(\mathbb{R})$ by mapping a quaternion
$ a + bi + cj + dk $ to a $4 \times 4$ matrix:
$$\Phi(a + bi + cj + dk) = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & d \\
-b & a & -d & c \\
-c & d & a & -b \\
-d & -c & b & a 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
It is readily apparent that $ \Phi $ functions as both a ring morphism and an injective mapping; consequently, the image forms the precise subring required.
